# How to convert a GRIB file to CSV/ASCII

Tags: python, csv, ascii, grib

I have downloaded the ERA5-Land hourly-ECMWF climate reanalysis data from Copernicus. The data come in .grib format. It would be easy for me to manipulate the data in .csv or ASCII format. The idea is to have data presented in a "tabular" form with the columns: time/longitude/latitude/precipitation/temperature.

I have done some reading and I have found the following solutions that I cannot implement.

1. wgrib2 : I can't seem to find the place to download it (or link not working)
2. Pygrib : I cannot use this python library because I am using Windows 10
3. Google Earth Engine: I cannot find a script available online.

Using Windows 10 as my OS:

1. What Python library (with script if possible) can I use to convert GRIB to CSV or ASCII?
2. Or where can I find a script to do the conversion on Google Earth Engine?
3. Or any software that can allow me to do such conversion?

Comment: CSV is really not a good format for complex raster data of the sort stored in grib files, would an ESRI ASCII grid not be better (then GDAL can do the conversion)

Comment: @IanTurton I didn't think of using the ASCII. I can give it a try. Could you perhaps explain how to proceed with GDAL?

Comment: may be you could rewrite your question to describe what you actually want to do

Comment: `pygrib` should run under Windows 10. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62937944/42659. I was able to install it and import the package. I'm not familiar with the file format though so didn't go further than that.